# Como enviar Json al controlador en asp.net core 3.1?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net

Estoy tratando de enviar un objeto **JSON** al controlador en **asp.net** de la siguiente forma:

Vista:

```
<a onclick="obtenerC()" class="btn btn-info text-white" style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px;">
   <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Cargar
</a>
```

```
function obtenerC() {
    console.log("Entro a obtener clientes");
    var clientes = [
        { id: "1", nombre: "Mariana", edad: "34", fecha: "28-10-1992" },
        { id: "2", nombre: "Lucio", edad: "56", fecha: "19-11-1988" },
        { id: "3", nombre: "Fernando", edad: "43", fecha: "01-11-1984" },
    ];

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/Articulos/ObtenerClientes",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(clientes),
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        },
    });
}
```

```
public IActionResult ObtenerClientes([FromBody] Persona clientes)
{
   var resultado = clientes;
   return View(resultado);
}
```

Ahora cuando veo en la consola el resultado me sale el siguiente error. Es de anotar que mi controlador se encuentra dentro del área Admin

> Error de lectura XML: no se encuentra el elemento raíz Ubicación:
>   https://localhost:44300/Admin/Articulos/ObtenerClientes Número de
>   línea 1, columna 1:

Comment: Prueba de setear el `contentType` como `application/json` y del lado del server, declara el tipo del parámetro como una colección de `Persona`, que realmente es lo que mandas des del cliente.

Comment: en tu controller al método `ObtenerClientes` indicas que es de tipo `POST`? `[HttpPost("[action]")]`

Answer (score 0):

en tu controlador debes usar una lista ya que desde tu ajax envias una lista de Persona no una sola Persona:

```
public IActionResult ObtenerClientes([FromBody] List<Persona> clientes)
{
var resultado = clientes;
return View(resultado);
}
```